# PHP preg_replace pass matched values to a function

Tags: php

I googled more than 2 hours about this problem I want to fix but still no luck...anyone please help on this...

I want save all user text input to mysql database and in php I need to convert all non alphanumeric char to unicode for chinese characters and other symbols. So how preg_replace can pass current matched value pass it to a function for conversion.

Example: 
    preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", turn_unicode($matchedvaluehere), $string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php
or
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php
in older versions of PHP.

```
<?php
$subject = 'Aaaaaa Bbb';

preg_replace_callback_array(
    [
        '~[a]+~i' => function ($match) {
    echo strlen($match[0]), ' matches for "a" found', PHP_EOL;
         },
        '~[b]+~i' => function ($match) {
            echo strlen($match[0]), ' matches for "b" found', PHP_EOL;
        }
    ],
    $subject
);
?>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11821769)

Comment: True. This is the best I could do on a mobile phone. Close enough?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use group and then backreference it in callback param. Something like

```
preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9 ])/", turn_unicode("\$1"), $string);
```

Comment: No; your turn-unicode function doesn't know what "\1" means. You'd have to use some horrible eval construction.